how do i fix this error everytime i try to enlist a product using CJJdropshipping on my Wordpress Website?

[can someone help me fix this , im trying to enlist a product and its not working using CJJdropshipping on my wordpress website , Support of cjjdropshipping support tells me to Hi there, do you have WPCF Editor tab in your woocommerce store? If yes, you may adjust the time to "60"   , I did that and the problem still there can someone help me fix this please?


This is a third-party service and plugin - you're going to have to keep working with them to get help.
